# got this error using mapkit, Unable to retrieve CarrierName

Tags: swift, background, mapkit

I got this error when i use mapkit:

```
[LogMessageLogging] 6.1 Unable to retrieve CarrierName. CTError: domain-2, code-5, errStr:((os/kern) failure)
```

I have been googled it for a while. i still can't find any solution.

Please help me. thanks.